# LoadBalancer inside RabbitMQ Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, cluster-computing, load-balancing

I'm new to RabbitMQ and Kubernetes world, and I'm trying to achieve the following objectives:

1. I've deployed successfully a RabbitMQ Cluster on Kubernetes(minikube) and exposed via loadbalancer(doing minikube tunnel on local)
2. I can connect successfully to my Queue with a basic Spring Boot app. I can send and receive message from my cluster.
3. In my clusters i have 4 nodes. I have applied the mirror queue policy (HA), and the created queue is mirrored also on other nodes.

This is my cluster configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: rabbit-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  # echo -n "cookie-value" | base64
  RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: V0lXVkhDRFRDSVVBV0FOTE1RQVc=
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-config
data:
  enabled_plugins: |
    [rabbitmq_federation,rabbitmq_management,rabbitmq_federation_managementrabbitmq_peer_discovery_k8s].
  rabbitmq.conf: |
    loopback_users.guest = false
    listeners.tcp.default = 5672
    cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend  = rabbit_peer_discovery_k8s
    cluster_formation.k8s.host = kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
    cluster_formation.k8s.address_type = hostname
    cluster_formation.node_cleanup.only_log_warning = true
    ##cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend = rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config
    ##cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.1 = rabbit@rabbitmq-0.rabbitmq.rabbits.svc.cluster.local
    ##cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.2 = rabbit@rabbitmq-1.rabbitmq.rabbits.svc.cluster.local
    ##cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.3 = rabbit@rabbitmq-2.rabbitmq.rabbits.svc.cluster.local
```

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  serviceName: rabbitmq
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rabbitmq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rabbitmq
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: rabbitmq
      initContainers:
      - name: config
        image: busybox
        command: ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'cp /tmp/config/rabbitmq.conf /config/rabbitmq.conf && ls -l /config/ && cp /tmp/config/enabled_plugins /etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins']
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /tmp/config/
          readOnly: false
        - name: config-file
          mountPath: /config/
        - name: plugins-file
          mountPath: /etc/rabbitmq/
      containers:
      - name: rabbitmq
        image: rabbitmq:3.8-management
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/sh
                - -c
                - >
                  until rabbitmqctl --erlang-cookie ${RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE} await_startup; do sleep 1; done;
                  rabbitmqctl --erlang-cookie ${RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE} set_policy ha-two "" '{"ha-mode":"exactly", "ha-params": 2, "ha-sync-mode": "automatic"}'
        ports:
        - containerPort: 15672
          name: management
        - containerPort: 4369
          name: discovery
        - containerPort: 5672
          name: amqp
        env:
        - name: RABBIT_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: RABBIT_POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: RABBITMQ_NODENAME
          value: rabbit@$(RABBIT_POD_NAME).rabbitmq.$(RABBIT_POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
        - name: RABBITMQ_USE_LONGNAME 
          value: "true"
        - name: RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE
          value: "/config/rabbitmq"
        - name: RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: rabbit-secret
              key: RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE
        - name: K8S_HOSTNAME_SUFFIX
          value: .rabbitmq.$(RABBIT_POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/rabbitmq
          readOnly: false
        - name: config-file
          mountPath: /config/
        - name: plugins-file
          mountPath: /etc/rabbitmq/
      volumes:
      - name: config-file
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: plugins-file
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: rabbitmq-config
          defaultMode: 0755
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "standard"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 50Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 15672
    targetPort: 15672
    name: management
  - port: 4369
    targetPort: 4369
    name: discovery
  - port: 5672
    targetPort: 5672
    name: amqp
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
```

If I understood correctly, rabbitmq with HA receives message on one node(master) and then response is mirrored to slave, right?

But if I want to load balance the workload? For example suppose that I sends 200 messages per second.

These 200 messages are received all from the master node. What I want, instead, is that these 200 messages are distributed across nodes, for example 100 messages are received from node1, 50 messages are received on node 2 and the rest on node 3. It's possible to do that? And if yes, how can I achieve it on kubernetes?